# Run Symfony2 command in background

Tags: symfony, queue, rabbitmq

I've a queue of emails for send to customers. I'm spooling emails: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/spool.html

Using this command:

```
php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```

The problem is, how to run this command in background?. I mean don't have to execute this command from console whenever I want to send email queues

I solved this using a crontab like explained here: http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/04/27/spooling-emails-with-symfony2-on-vps-and-shared-hosting/

But for me, using crontab not appears the best solution. I read also about RabbitMQ and her bundle for Symfony2 but with this I have to run another command to consume the queue:

```
./app/console rabbitmq:consumer -m 50 queue_email
```

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Crontab is very fine, what do you not like about it?

Comment: Because is the first time I use crontab for run taks in enviorment production and I don't know if this is the best solution for run task in backgroung.

Comment: This is an industry standard, I recommand it, mail does not need real-time (Rabbit). Just don't forget the `--env=prod` parameter ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks @Damien I'll continue using this.